# QString assignment releases allocation

Tags: qt, qt5

I have a simple QT code that is called very often. It has to process some data and then format it into a `QString` that is sen sent to a `QwtText` object. Right now the function every time creates a `QString` object with all the dynamic memory allocation work. Then this object is destroyed and memory deallocated after the function is done.

I'm trying to optimize the code by creating a local class `QString` variable that would hold this formatted string. The idea is to prevent repeated `malloc/free` calls. However, right after the first string assignment it appears that the `QString` object frees and allocates the memory again, judging by the number returned by `int QString::capacity()` [link](https://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qstring.html#capacity).

```
m_valuesLabelText.clear();
// Capacity is 1011
m_valuesLabelText += "<table width=50>";
// Capacity is 16
```

Is there any way to prevent this re-allocation and convince `QString` to reuse the old buffer?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QString::clear` deallocates, as you can see by reading the source, e.g. [here](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/tools/qstring.cpp.html).

`QString::resize` does not deallocate, so it can be a solution to your problem: `yourString.resize(0)`.

Use `QString::reserve` to allocate a suitable buffer.

Comment: Agh, I've misunderstood the documentation for `void QString::clear()`. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
QString & oftenCalledFunction(BS *bs, QString &p)
{
   p += "assignNew";
}

void func()
{
   QString p(MAX_SIZE); //set MAX_SIZE appropriately.
   BS bs;
   p = oftenCalledFunction(&bs, p);
}
```

This way you allocate on stack, avoiding malloc calls. Does this help?
Malloc is not very bad though, it doesnt straightaway release the memory back to the system. Most free store library internally implement some kind of pool allocation strategy.

Comment: I've had this code before (it's the legacy code). The problem is that on every call to `func()` `malloc` is called and then `free` when it returns. And I have lots of calls to `func()`. I don't see a point of reallocating the same object every time. It is not a lot, but still overhead.